# Get the next row that matches criteria

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a stored procedure that returns the total earnings from someone and checks if the current amount is outside the expected input.

The total earning is inputed manually and sometimes people insert the wrong amount, like putting in an extra 0 or forgetting one number.

The stored procedure calculates the earnings since the last input. Somethings are expected and the stored procedure tells if the row is outside the expected value (like if the value is negative for example)

What I need to do "ignore" those inputs and calculate based on the next row without error. For example in the query bellow:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (
    [Date] DATETIME,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    [TotalEarnings] DECIMAL(10,2),
    [PartialEarnings] DECIMAL(10,2),
    [ConsecultiveErrors] INT
);

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20180510 00:00:00', 'John', 1000.00, NULL, 0);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20180509 00:00:00', 'John', 9000.00, -8000.00, 3);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20180508 00:00:00', 'John', 80.00, 8920.00, 2);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20180507 00:00:00', 'John', 700.00, -720.00, 1);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20180506 00:00:00', 'John', 600.00, 100.00, 0);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20180505 00:00:00', 'John', 5000.00, -4400.00, 2);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20180504 00:00:00', 'John', 400.00, 4600.00, 1);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20180503 00:00:00', 'John', 300.00, 100.00, 0);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20180502 00:00:00', 'John', 20.00, 180.00, 2);
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('20180501 00:00:00', 'John', 100.00, -80.00, 1);

SELECT
    [t].[Date],
    [t].[Name],
    [t].[TotalEarnings],
    [t].[PartialEarnings],
    [t].[ConsecultiveErrors]
FROM
    @Table AS [t]
```

I would need to calculate the avarage from the difference between the row from day 1 until the first day without error (the 3rd) giving $100 to the 1st and 2nd day each.

How can I achieve that?

[EDIT1] So the last column shows the amount of rows with errors in a sequence. They use that, because the error is calculated using the Partial Value, and the partial value is calculated using a LAG/LEAD function. So one wrong input actually can cause two or more rows to be considered "wrong"

Comment: `where PartialEarnings > 0` would remove the negatives... but how would we know what other *errors* there are? What logic determines if there was a *wrong amount* or if they *forgot one number*?

Comment: About the errors the procedure already has the parameters to calculate the errors. The last column returns the consecultive errors found. If you look closely the first one gives an error for having a negative partial value, and the next partial gives error for being greater than the expected value (some calculations are made in the procedure)

Comment: You need to post the sproc, or at least help us understand what you're determining is an erroe.

Comment: Well done on the ddl and example data. We are missing something with the errors. To start off day 1 reports an error, and day 2 shows an error, day 3 is good, you ask about the difference between day 1 and first day without error, the difference does not matter, if I mess up the input and input 1 million, and the second day I enter in 100 and it is correct, the difference has no bearing on expected results.

Comment: I would think you would want something to take the `Total Earnings` column and divide it by how many `X days` to get a base line of or approximation of the amount entered. Where x is a cycle of time, be it a month or a year ect... using an error record will only give you false results.

Comment: @Random_User Ok, so the first day shows and error because of the next day (which has an incorrect input) but the third day is correctedly inputed , so the error is because of one incorrect input, but that input caused two days to become errors (because the error is based on the partial value) I know it doesn't make much sense but that's how the place works. If you need more info I'm happy to give them if I can

Comment: I would base the approximate value on the average using the history of non error values, `select [TotalEarnings] / (sum of number of entries of error 0) from table where [ConsecultiveErrors] = 0` - assuming total earning is a running total of the value given.

Answer (score 0):

Your descriptions are slightly confusing, though I think this does what you need it to?

The `CTE` uses a conditional running `sum` to group the rows by `ConsecutiveErrors = 1` to `ConsecutiveErrors = 0` when sorted in `DateValue` (Don't use reserved words such as `Date` for object names) order.  It also provides the `TotalEarnings` either as a negative for the first row or a positive for the last row and `0` otherwise, the `sum` of which gives you the difference between the first and last row in the `ErrorGroup`.

From this, you can then either return the correct `PartialEarnings` value from the `ConsecutiveErrors = 0` row or the `average` of the `EarningsDiffence` across the number of rows within the `ErrorGroup` minus `1` (ie: the number of erroneous rows within the group):

```
declare @t as table (
    DateValue datetime,
    Name varchar(100),
    TotalEarnings decimal(10,2),
    PartialEarnings decimal(10,2),
    ConsecutiveErrors int
);

insert into @t values ('20180510 00:00:00', 'John', 1000.00, NULL, 0);
insert into @t values ('20180509 00:00:00', 'John', 9000.00, -8000.00, 3);
insert into @t values ('20180508 00:00:00', 'John', 80.00, 8920.00, 2);
insert into @t values ('20180507 00:00:00', 'John', 700.00, -720.00, 1);
insert into @t values ('20180506 00:00:00', 'John', 600.00, 100.00, 0);
insert into @t values ('20180505 00:00:00', 'John', 5000.00, -4400.00, 2);
insert into @t values ('20180504 00:00:00', 'John', 400.00, 4600.00, 1);
insert into @t values ('20180503 00:00:00', 'John', 300.00, 100.00, 0);
insert into @t values ('20180502 00:00:00', 'John', 20.00, 180.00, 2);
insert into @t values ('20180501 00:00:00', 'John', 100.00, -80.00, 1);

with g as
(
    select DateValue
        ,Name
        ,TotalEarnings
        ,PartialEarnings
        ,ConsecutiveErrors
        ,sum(case when ConsecutiveErrors = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by DateValue) as ErrorGroup
        ,case when ConsecutiveErrors = 1 then -TotalEarnings
                when ConsecutiveErrors = 0 then TotalEarnings
                else 0
                end as EarningsDifference
    from @t
)
select DateValue
        ,Name
        ,TotalEarnings
        ,PartialEarnings
        ,ConsecutiveErrors
        ,ErrorGroup
        ,case when ConsecutiveErrors = 0
                then PartialEarnings
                else sum(EarningsDifference) over (partition by ErrorGroup)
                    / (count(EarningsDifference) over (partition by ErrorGroup)-1)
                end as AverageEarnings
from g
order by DateValue
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------+
|        DateValue        | Name | TotalEarnings | PartialEarnings | ConsecutiveErrors | ErrorGroup | AverageEarnings |
+-------------------------+------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------+
| 2018-05-01 00:00:00.000 | John |        100.00 | -80.00          |                 1 |          1 | 100.000000      |
| 2018-05-02 00:00:00.000 | John |         20.00 | 180.00          |                 2 |          1 | 100.000000      |
| 2018-05-03 00:00:00.000 | John |        300.00 | 100.00          |                 0 |          1 | 100.000000      |
| 2018-05-04 00:00:00.000 | John |        400.00 | 4600.00         |                 1 |          2 | 100.000000      |
| 2018-05-05 00:00:00.000 | John |       5000.00 | -4400.00        |                 2 |          2 | 100.000000      |
| 2018-05-06 00:00:00.000 | John |        600.00 | 100.00          |                 0 |          2 | 100.000000      |
| 2018-05-07 00:00:00.000 | John |        700.00 | -720.00         |                 1 |          3 | 100.000000      |
| 2018-05-08 00:00:00.000 | John |         80.00 | 8920.00         |                 2 |          3 | 100.000000      |
| 2018-05-09 00:00:00.000 | John |       9000.00 | -8000.00        |                 3 |          3 | 100.000000      |
| 2018-05-10 00:00:00.000 | John |       1000.00 | NULL            |                 0 |          3 | NULL            |
+-------------------------+------+---------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------+
```